# How to branch traffic weight in alb's listener when there is a legacy server (EC2) and a new server (ECS-Fargate). (with ECS Blue/Green Deploy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

For the above question, create a target group on each server and set the listener weight distribution. However, when a new server uses ECS BlueGreen deployment, if there is a target group (legacy server) other than the target group set in the Deploy step, an error occurs and deployment is not possible.

I'm wondering if you have any solutions or suggestions.

I tried to get an answer from the official documentation, but there were no similar cases.
I posted a question, but am waiting for a response.

Comment: Are you using CloudFormation/IaC or are these manually created resources? Can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, i'm using "CloudFormation/IaC" (CDK).

However, the problem is that when the Blue of green target group is added to the legacy listener (both cdk and manual methods), the following error occurs during the next codedeploy process. `The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Only target group in ECS deployment group (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:<Region>:<account>:targetgroup/tg-ecs-green, arn :aws:elasticloadbalancing:<Region>:<account>:targetgroup/tg-ecs-blue) can be set on listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:<Region>:<account>:listener-rule/ app/alb-dev/....
`